# Codeigniter is ok with localhost, but on a live server it says "database.php does not exist", how can I locate my database if I use linux cPanel?

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, cpanel

I have been searching stackoverflow and all across google to find and answer to this, but I have no luck.

I think I know what my problem is, but I don't know the solution for it.

In my codeigniter index.php configuration on my localhost, my code looks like this.

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
switch ($root) {
    case '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myproject':
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
    break;
    default:
        define('ENVIRONTMENT', 'production');
    break;
}
```

I am now using a live host with a linux hosted server with cPanel, and I don't know how to locate public_html, can someone help me on what do I have to put in this "case '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myproject':"??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `controllers`, `models` and `libraries` file names must start with uppercase character. for example : `application/models/Database.php`.

Comment: How did you transfer the files to the server. Try using an ftp software to transfer the files to the server this will keep all files intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cpanel/WHM Default directory for public_html is:

/home/***cpanel-username***/public_html

[Here are some more common directories if needed](http://www.webhostingbuzz.com/wiki/common-paths-cpanel-and-whm/)

Comment: Problem is solved! Thank you very much, my website is now live :D

Comment: Sorry Its my first time doing this. Thank you!

Comment: Better late than never! HAHA